# OnPause() not called when relaunch activity in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, activity-lifecycle

I've chosen to save the persistent application state in the `OnPause()` method to my database because `OnPause()` is guaranteed to be called before the application gets killed according to [the documentation of the activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle).

Now I am facing following behaviour using eclipse and avd emulator (api level 8):
1. I start my application via eclipse - Instance1
2. I start my application via eclipse again - Instance2

Now Instance1 is being terminated without calling `OnPause()`!

Could somebody please explain me why `OnPause()` is not being called? I thought it is guaranteed to be called always. If this is not the case, maybe because of the way eclipse terminates Instance1 process, then I would like to know if I could change this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start the application via eclipse, it will effectively rip the rug out from any instance of the same app already running on the device or an emulator.  This will never happen in practice, only when running from eclipse.

So you can plan on onPause() always being called.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You gave me certainity that i can rely on onPause always on a device. Anyway i would like to wait a little with accepting yours as an answer because i hope somebody has an idea how we can get the emulator to behave the same as a device.

Comment: The app will behave the same on the emulator as on a device.  If you run the app "com.a.b" from eclipse and "com.a.b" is already running on the emulator, or on a real device, "com.a.b" will be killed without any notification given to the app (as if the battery were pulled from the device or the power plug pulled while the emulator is running).  However, if the app is closed during normal operation onPause() will be called.

Answer (score 0):

what you mean you start application via eclipse - instance 1 and 2?

when click on run button, emulator (in your case or a real device) runs your application. please don't run it in other AVD (if i get correctly based on your instance 1 and 2). If you have put log code in your onCreate() and onPause() methods, For example Log.i(TAG, "I'm in onCreate()!");, you should see it in logcat. therefore, when you launch your app you will see onCreate message and when you click on home button for example, you will see onPause() message.

This is the way which is guaranteed to be called.

Comment: i mean i start the application on the same emulator and then start it again on the same emulator which kills the first instance without calling onPause. i made the tests with the log messages before asking here. log messages of onPause and onStop do not appear which shows me that onPause is not called in this scenario. i would expect an emulator to respect the lifecycle as well, but it seems not to be the case.